# SVG images in AMP article Microdata?

Tags: svg, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets, amp-html

When attempting to validate a `schema.org/Article` against Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), I noticed that it gives an error if you specify an SVG image:

> The value provided for *logo* must be a valid URL.
>
> **Required by:**
>
> AMP Articles ([what's this?](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles))

When the URL is changed to have a `.png` (or `.jpg`, `.bmp`, `.webp`, etc.) extension, rather than `.svg`, it passes validation.

Here is the example I'm working with:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Example" />
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://example.com" />
        <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <meta itemprop="url" content="http://example.com/logo.svg" />
            <meta itemprop="width" content="600" />
            <meta itemprop="height" content="60" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2016-01-05T12:43" />
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2016-01-05T12:43" />
    <meta itemprop="headline" content="Example" />
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Example" />
    <meta itemprop="author" content="Example" />
    <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="http://example.com/article" />
    <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://example.com/article.jpg" />
        <meta itemprop="width" content="1200" />
        <meta itemprop="height" content="800" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Changing the other image's URL's extension will also produce the error.

I was unable to find any information on why it rejects SVGs in the [Rich Snippets documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles#article_markup_properties) or the [AMP HTML spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/spec). Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Just to be clear: This is not required by AMP. It’s only Google that (maybe) requires this for displaying their search results features. It’s perfectly fine/valid to provide SVG images with Schema.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From one of the links you gave: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles

> Images should be in .jpg, .png, or. gif format.

Why? Who knows. Perhaps because SVGs still have some support issues in some browsers (particularly older ones).

Comment: Good catch! I guess we just need to assume that those same rules apply to the logo then. Weird.

Answer (score 8):

Google has updated the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/carousels/top-stories#logo_guidelines) and specifically mentioned svg.

Logo image files should be raster (for example, .jpg, .png, .gif), not vector (for example, .svg), with no animation.

Answer (score 1):

Update: 2022 - after reading the google documentation, it seems they do now accept svgs. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/logo#structured-data-type-definitions